# How to update many-to-many table: delete, delete all, insert, reinsert

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite new with php/mysql, this is my first real solo project from the beginning. I am creating a database for a library in mysql on apache/php, and I'm having some problems with the structure and organization of the database.
I have the following tables:

1. Books contains info on each book
2. Tags - tagid and tag name (e.g 301: Suspense, 302: Crime, 303: Mystery)
3. Booktags the tags associated with each book (e.g. Bookid 27 TagId 301, BookId 27, tagId 302)

The user can then search for books by tag (I query the Booktags table and find all the books associated with a particular tag.

When entering or updating info on a book the user enters a list of tags (comma separated) or chooses from a predefined popup list.

I'm coming now to the question of updating the info. If a user chooses to change the existing  tags that were defined for a book I want to remove the ones that are no longer necessary. Should I check the existing tags against the new list and remove the ones that are not relevant? Or is it better to delete all the tags associated with this book and insert only the relevant ones (assuming that in some cases I will be deleting and reinserting the same thing)?

Any advice would be appreciated (also if you think I'm going about things in a stupid or inefficient way please suggest a way to do it better)

Answer (score 2):

Simply delete every tags and insert the news.
It will cost less time, and less energy